# How to determine the size of an instance?

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, unsafe

I have set my project to accept unsafe code and have the following helper Class to determine the size of an instance:

```
struct MyStruct
    {
        public long a;
        public long b;
    }

public static class CloneHelper
    {
        public unsafe static void GetSize(BookSetViewModel book)
        {
            long n = 0;

            MyStruct inst;
            inst.a = 0;
            inst.b = 0;
            n = Marshal.SizeOf(inst);
        }
}
```

This works perfectly fine with a struct. However as soon as I use the actual class-instance that is passed in:

```
public unsafe static void GetSize(BookSetViewModel book)
        {
            long n = 0;


            n = Marshal.SizeOf(book);
        }
```

I get this error:

> Type 'BookSetViewModel' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure;
>   no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

Any idea how I could fix this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it really depends on what you mean by the "size" of an instance. There's the size of the single object in memory, but you *usually* need to think about any objects that the root object refers to. That's how much memory *may* be reclaimable after the root becomes eligible for garbage collection... but you can't just add them up, as those objects may be referred to by multiple *other* objects, and indeed there may be repeated references even within a single object.

[This blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings) shows some code I've used before to determine the size of the raw objects (header + fields), disregarding any extra cost due to the objects that one object refers to. It's not something I would use in production code, but it's useful for experimenting with how large an object is under varying circumstances.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I need to have a rough estimate how big (bytes) each BookSetViewModel is and show it accordingly on each tab. So that the customer gets an idea how big the current book is. I will that blog you sent and get back to you. Many Thanks

Comment: @Kave: But why is that of interest to the customer? If several books all refer to the same very long author name (as a single string object), should that be included or not? It seems very odd for a *customer* to be interested in internal memory usage, unless you're actually writing a profiler.

Comment: sorry what I meant is not a normal book, but a book in trading terms. Therefore each book is unique automatically. We have some memory problems as if the customer loads up too many books, the memory gets clogged up (still WinXp with 4 GB memory limitation). Therefore I need to render the tab (on which the book sits) with different colors, warning the user that too many big books have been opened up and he should better close some. etc. Hope it makes sense

Comment: @Kave: The size of the direct object itself will be the same for all objects - so it sounds like you're actually interested in the data *within* the object. I suspect that an exact figure won't be terribly useful there - but if you work out what takes the bulk of the data (e.g. large arrays and strings) then that should give a reasonable "rough estimate".

Comment: Each book has a number of sub-tabs (layouts). Each layout has different columns. But the underlying rows are the same for each layout.  I could also count the rows and calculate it against the columns to come up with a measurement alternatively...

Comment: Exactly, each book has a different size of a ObservableCollection. (Rows)

Comment: @Kave: Right. If each row either has the exact same size (no variable-size columns such as strings) or has an easily guesstimated size (calculate size per string + constant) then you could work out something from that. Just displaying the number of rows may well give a good enough approximation to accuracy - as well as showing a *meaningful* number.

Comment: @Heslacher: Fixed, thanks. (My blog moved a while ago.)